# Ionic modal and content not rendering well

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, angular11

I created a modal component but it only renders the content well when opening it the first time. Subsequent openings the modal does not render the content correctly. The header can be hidden, font color is changed, all content can be hidden e.t.c.

I have declared it in the module that opens it and added it in entrycomponents.
Can it be that the css is not loaded correctly.

I'm using ionic 5.6.5 and angular 11.

module containg the modal component

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomePage, AllordersComponent],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [AllordersComponent]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

code for opening modal

```
async openModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: AllordersComponent
      });
      return await modal.present();
    }
```

code inside the modal component html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>



<ion-content>
  <div id="container">
    <strong>Ready to create an app?</strong>
    <ion-button (click)="dismiss()">Close modal</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

code for closing the modal

```
async dismiss() {
    return await this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }
```

Also I noted the rendering problem occurs only on firefox browser.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors in console of firefox?

Comment: The changing behaviour you see looks like an issue with the (lazyloaded) module to me. My guess would be, that you don't need the `EntryComponent` part. (I know that there was some need for it in Ionic 4) But in Ionic 5 I have a project, which uses Modals without the `EntryComponent` definition.

Comment: @iamentafaz There are no errors.

Comment: no Idea about the firefox. Only that the <strong> tag is rendered differently in older versions. See: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Cstrong%3E

Comment: @DavidB. I have removed the entrycomponent part but still no change.

Comment: The issue appears when I'm on developer tools using the responsive design mode for different devices. When in full browser window the modal displays correctly.

Comment: Maybe related to this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405349/ionic-4-selects-not-working-in-firefox-responsive-design-mode

Comment: That did not help

Comment: i think you have to removed "AllordersComponent"  from home page module and add into "AppModule" in "imports" tage. import ".module" file